# google drive address in google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, drive

I am new to google colaboratory.

In My Drive there are my required files. the address of train.py file is:

`gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Project_Folder/DELTA-master/DELTA-master/train.py`.

I use this address in a cell as follow to run train.py:

`! python gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Project_Folder/DELTA-master/DELTA-master/train.py`

but I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdrive/My
>   Drive/Colab
>   Notebooks/Project_Folder/DELTA-master/DELTA-master/train.py'

Can anyone help me?!

Comment: try a `/` before `gdrive`, like this: /gdrive/My Drive/...

Comment: I tried it . But I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Use this to generate an authentication code and make the drive accessible.

**Then in colab, under files in the left side tab, see if you can locate the file. Then right click on the file and select copy path.**

Or you can use

```
/content/drive/My\ Drive/ <path to your file in gdrive>
```

Don't forget to put "\" whereever the foldername has space in it